# Extending Entity Framework for storing information about queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

The goal is to extend Entity Framework in a way that for each query to the original database, a separate call with the identical data would be made to a different DB.

The purpose of this behavior is to track history of actions on a specific database. The history would be stored in a different database, possibly even in a different server.

What are the possibilities to have such behavior in form of either an extension to EF or using a specific EF configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EF DataContext is implemented as a partial class. You could override `SaveChanges` to do what you need (I'll assume your DataContext is called EfEntities):

```
public partial class EfEntities
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var changes = from e in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                      where e.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged
                      select e;

        foreach (var change in changes)
        {
            if (change.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
            {
                // Handle added entities
            }
            else if (change.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified)
            {
                // Handle modified entities
                var item = change.Cast<IEntity>().Entity;
                var originalValues = this.Entry(item).OriginalValues;
                var currentValues = this.Entry(item).CurrentValues;

                foreach (string propertyName in originalValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    var original = originalValues[propertyName];
                    var current = currentValues[propertyName];

                    if (!Equals(original, current))
                    {
                        // log propertyName: original --> current
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (change.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                // Handle deleted entities
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```